# NetBeans Applet Web Start with (use project Main class)

Tags: java, netbeans, applet, java-web-start

So I followed this tutorial to create an applet that can run online. (I got it to work on a web host.)
[Integrating an Applet in a Web Application](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/applets.html).

Under the tutorial they made a descriptor under the applet called org.me.Hello.MyApplet, that is specifically used for the "code" tag in thefor the web applications index.html

```html
<applet code="org.me.hello.MyApplet" archive="HelloApplet.jar"></applet>
```

My question is, I never made a `urlpath.FunGame` for my applet in the web start descriptor, so I am not sure what to put as the code tag for the index file in the web application folder. Under Web Start of the project it says "applet descriptor (use project main class)"

Here is how my index file looks right now, I made "GameGUI.class" the code base as I am unsure of how to fully use this example snippet. 
My main class is located in the class GameGUI of project FunGame.

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <script src="//www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    var attributes = {codebase: 'http://hellojar.elementfx.com/FunGame/',
                      code: 'GameGUI.class',
                      archive: 'FunGame.jar',
                      width: '800', 
                      height: '600'};
    var parameters = {java_arguments: '-Xmx256m'}; // customize per your needs
    var version = '1.6'; // JDK version
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you,
-Austin

EDIT: The error I get is GameGUI.class not found, as I do not know how to specify the main as my codebase

Trying variations of "main.GameGUI", "main.GameGUI.class", and "main" still no luck. Anymore hints would be appreciated

Comment: In what reference do you mean it is invalid? I am new to this, so obvious stuff is nothing for me haha. I am using a free web host development site for side things which can be found here http://hellojar.elementfx.com/index.html I have the example applet running. So in regards to your comment, do you mean that using an applet tag in itself is invalid, or what? ...I'm not getting whatever you are trying to say. Thank you!

Comment: See if [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html) will give you any answers.

Comment: Also take a look [at this](http://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/63-How-to-use-Java-applets-in-modern-browsers.html)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well if I cannot figure out to properly code the script tags then of course it will give me errors. I am asking for help with encoding it as the last time I made an applet I could use the applet tag just fine. I have been researching and looking around but I am getting confused since I do not have a Web Start descriptor for my project "FunGame".

Comment: @AndrewThompson I also had to make a JNLP last time when I used the applet tags, do I still need to do that, or no? I am sorry if I sound stupid, but this is new to me, I am trying to learn. :/

Comment: "_I am trying to learn_" Folks are trying to give you the resources to do that. There is a difference between _trying to learn_ and _making someone teach you_.

Comment: @csmckelvey Yes I understand, and I am getting there, but if you look at my updated question I cannot find anything that avoids using the codebase as I never set a pathway in my descriptor OR a way to call my main as the codebase. I am reading and reading but I cannot find anything on this specifically.

Comment: @AndrewThompson If you look at my revised post, am I at least moving in the right direction with this?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am glad you read the part where I stated that the applet tag was the EXAMPLE of the codebase I learned, not MY code. I am not using applet tags, I am pointing out the codebase reference path and I used the applet tag as an EXAMPLE. Thanks for not reading it all the way through and then making generalized assumptions. I might as well learn from someone who actually cares.